# matching quoted strings and unquoted words

Tags: python, regex

I try to write a regular expression to match eihter strings surrounded by double quotes (`"`) or words separated by space () and have them in a list in python.

I don't really understand the output of my code, can anybody give me a hint or explain what my regular expression is doing exactly?

here is my code:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('(\"[^\"]*\")|( [^ ]* )')
test = '"hello world." here are some words. "and more"'
print(regex.split(test))
```

I expect an output like this:

```
['"hello world."', ' here ', ' are ', ' some ', ' words. ', '"and more"']
```

but I get the following:

```
['', '"hello world."', None, '', None, ' here ', 'are', None, ' some ', 'words.', None, ' "and ', 'more"']
```

where does the empty strings and the `None`s come from.
and why does it match `"hello world."` but not `"and more"`.

Thanks for your help, and a happy new year for those who celebrate it today!

**EDIT:**
to be precise: i dont need the surrounding spaces but i need the surrounding quotes. this output would be fine too:

```
['"hello world."', 'here', 'are', 'some', 'words.', '"and more"']
```

**EDIT2:**

i ended up using `shlex.split()` like @PadraicCunningham suggested because it did exactly what i need and ihmo it is much more readable than regular expressions.

i still keep @TigerhawkT3's answer the accepted one because it solves the problem in the way i have asked it (with regular expressions).

Comment: Do you want get `' words '` or `' words. '`?

Comment: @KevinGuan thanks. this was just a typo. i fixed it. in this case i would need the dot. but i dont need the spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the quoted match first so it prioritizes that, and then non-whitespace characters:

```
>>> s = '"hello world." here are some words. "and more"'
>>> re.findall(r'"[^"]*"|\S+', s)
['"hello world."', 'here', 'are', 'some', 'words.', '"and more"']
```

You can get the same result with a non-greedy repeating pattern instead of the character set negation:

```
>>> re.findall(r'".*?"|\S+', s)
['"hello world."', 'here', 'are', 'some', 'words.', '"and more"']
```

Comment: Good point - @linluk, did you want to keep the spaces, e.g. `' here '` instead of `'here'`?

Comment: i dont need the spaces. so it is perfectly fine. i just need the quotes and they are still there.

Comment: @linluk no this is not the right way.. We are strugging to get the expected output like yours.. BUt you finally said , "this is not I wanted"..

Comment: you are right, i edit my question, so that the spaces are optional. then it should be clear why i have accepted the answer for the next one who read this.

Answer (score 2):

[shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) with `posix=False` will do it for you:

```
import shlex

test = '"hello world." here are some words. "and more"'

print(shlex.split(test,posix=False))
['"hello world."', 'here', 'are', 'some', 'words.', '"and more"']
```

if you did not want the quotes, you would leave posix as True:

```
print(shlex.split(test))

['hello world.', 'here', 'are', 'some', 'words.', 'and more']
```

Comment: i have not heard of `shlex` before. thanks for that. i try it. imho it is a really elegant approach. but i keep Tigerhawk's answer the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CSV, so use the appropriate tools:

```
import csv
lines = ['"hello world." here are some words. "and more"']

list(csv.reader(lines, delimiter=' ', quotechar='"'))
```

returns

```
[['hello world.', 'here', 'are', 'some', 'words.', 'and more']]
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. it is not a csv file/data, so i am not sure if i should misuse csv here.